# How to change setting for all modes except one?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, config, hl-line-mode

How can I chance an Emacs config setting (let's say "highlighting of current line") that I set in `.emacs` as `(global-hl-line-mode +1)`, to work for **all modes except one**.

For example, I want highlighting of current line to be on for all modes except `org-mode`.

A great solution would be one that would also be applicable to customizing theme to be different by major mode (though file type could work fine for this too).

Comment: I answered the first part but of the question but the second one probably has a very different one. Probably you should split this question in two,

Comment: @matteol think you're right, I'll edit to remove that and add a separate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you customize a mode adding functions to the [mode hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html). To disable the hl-line-mode use the following code

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'global-hl-line-mode) nil)))
```

For more complex cases it's better to define a new function and add it to the hook.